# Статус форума

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, пишу форум на php, столкнулся с такой проблемой: существует, так сказать, "статус форума" т.е. иконка, которая отображает пользователю, есть ли в форуме новые сообщения с момента его последнего посещения.
Не могли бы подсказать идею, каким образом такое можно осуществить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший вариант -

```
//получаем айди последнего прочитанного сообщения. По дате, например
$id = //last read message id
setcookie ('last read message',$id,time()+365.25*24*60*60);

//Получаем куки и смотрим есть ли запись
if(isset($_COOKIE['last read message'])){
$lastreadid = $_COOKIE['last read message'];
}else{
$lastreadid = 0;
}
```

Comment: а можно ли привязать это к id пользователя а не просто кукам?

Comment: Ладно, начнем с более простого к более сложному)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант а) Сохранять `timestamp` последнего посещения. Если в форуме есть сообщения с датой, больше данной временной отметки, значит есть новые сообщения.
Ну и далее тему можно развивать и вставлять всякие условия.

Вариант б) Посмотреть, как функционал реализован в готовых скриптах.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать подобный запрос к базе данных

```
$sql = 'select COUNT(*) from `messages` where `date` > \''.$last_visit_date.'\'';
```

Он выдаёт количество сообщений в БД, с момента **`$last_visit_date`**, соответственно написав в переменную дату/время последнего посещения пользователя - вы получите желаемое

Comment: не получит. т.е. получит, но встает 2 вопроса: 
1. когда форум перестанет быть непрочитанным - что надо сделать? или вечно будет висеть как непрочитанный?
2. когда именно надо обновлять поле date? в какой момент пребывания на форуме.

Comment: Есть слишком много вариантов ответа на оба вопроса! Как ТС предпочтёт - так и реализует

Answer (score 1):

- Пишете в поле пользователя колонку lastvisit
- в каждом сообщении пишите колонку время создания - timecreated
- при входе пользователя делаете выборку: выбрать lastvisit из таблицы юзеров где юзер id это (тут переменная сессии с id текущего юзера) и (!) пишете ее в сессию и обновляете значение колонки новым - так как юзер вновь вошел.
- далее, при каждой генерации форума проверяете MAX значение поля timecreated для данного форума, если timecreated  больше $_SESSION['lastvisit']  - выводим картинку с непрочитанными
- Далее нужно как то менять картинку, если форум был прочитанным, этот вопрос встанет в любом случае. Но тут не так просто, я бы завел отдельную таблицу под отслеживание, что то вроде:

-- id, post, forum, user, read

и как то с ними играться.
колонка **read** - отмечаем прочитано / не прочитано
Я бы порекомендовал так все и реализовывать сразу.